# How to install multiple version of IE (IE6,7) on virtual pc

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, virtual-pc

I want to use ie7 on windows virutal pc, but to no avail. Below is what I have done.

I downoaded and installed three files from the link below:

1. WindowsXPMode_en-us.exe

   2.Windows6.1-KB958559-x64-RefreshPkg.msu

   3.Windows6.1-KB977206-x64.msu

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

After installation, I can run Windows XP virtual machine. But it has IE6. I have to have multiple version of IE.

Then I downled a file

XPSP3-IE7.exe

From http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

Then I run XPSP3-IE7.exe, which is a IE7Compat.vhd.

My question is how to use IE7Compat.vhd.

Any step-by-step installation instructions will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry but you can't have multiple versions of IE on a single XP machine, there's simply no way to have different side-by-side versions of the same browser.

If you need different browser versions for your tests you are going to need separate Viratual PC images of Win XP, for each of the versions. So if you want to test IE 6, 7 and 8 you need to create 3 different virtual PC disk images of XP and then install each version of the browser on each of them.

If your host machine is a Windows 7 machine (Professional, Enterprise or Ultimate) there's a simpler way to do this, by using the Windows 7 "XP Mode". You'll have to create 3 different "XP modes" anyway (which underneath are simply three different virtual PC disk images) and then install the three different browsers there as explained in this post by the Microsoft guys themselves:

[Testing Multiple Versions of IE on One PC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/02/04/testing-multiple-versions-of-ie-on-one-pc.aspx)

Hope that helps!

Comment: @juandg Thank for pointing that out. My question is how to use IE7Compat.vhd extracted from XPSP3-IE7.exe downloaded from  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

Comment: What you downloaded is a whole Virtual PC disk image (files with a .vhd extension are virtual hard drives). What you have to do is go to Virtual PC and click on Create Virtual Machine, it will open a wizard and on step 3 (I think) it will ask you about the hard drive, there select the "Load VHD" option and then navigate to IE7Compat.vhd. That will create a new XP virtual machine with whatever is on that Virtual Disk

Comment: @juandg Thanks. I cannot find Create Virtual Machine under Virtual PC. I am using WIndows 7 prof. WHen I click Virtual PC, Windows Explorer shows up, which contains one virtual machine file.

Comment: You are right!, there is technically no GUI for Virtual PC, it's integrated into Windows 7 so it just looks like a Windows Explorer menu, but it's not.

If you look towards the top of the Window, there is a Create Virtual Machine button, click that and it will open the wizard that guides you through the virtual machine creation process.

Comment: @juandg  Thank you so much, very appreciate your prompt help. It works! Make my day!

Comment: @Pingpong no problem at all! I'm very glad I could help ;-)